# SQL multiple join reference table from different tables

Tags: sql-server, database, join, sql-server-2014

I am working with MSSQL. As long as I have been working on a project with a customer who bought our software, we are at the final step. At that point we have to give them some SQL queries to get some reports from MSSQL database.

As I am not a familiar with SQL I am having a problem with joining multiple tables.

I have searched some and created a query but the problem is joining a table with others which has no common column with the table I noticed after FROM tag.

Let me explain a little:

I have 5 tables "x", "y", "z", "w", "m".

"x" table have common columns with "y", "z" and "w" tables

"m" table has a common column with "y" table

I want to select one another column from "m" for my report how can I join "x" with that table,

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? This is an extremely common scenario. You just join the tables you need. All tables don't have to join to the first table in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can join x to y, and then join the combination of x and y to m. You don't need to select any of the columns from y if you want your result to have only columns from x and m. Something like:

```
SELECT x.column_from_x, m.column_from_m
    FROM x
    JOIN y
    ON x.xy_common_column = y.xy_common_column
    JOIN m
    ON m.my_common_column = y.my_common_column
```

Any `WHERE` clause you might want can follow this. There's a more concrete example here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191430(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Hello, i will update your suggestion's result asap, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is, indeed, a very basic question, but here you go.

```
SELECT * 
FROM X
    INNER JOIN Y ON X.XYColumn = Y.XYColumn
    INNER JOIN M ON M.YMColumn = Y.YMColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

Since M, Y and X have something in common, you can use the code below

```
SELECT
M.Col,
X,CoL
FROM M
INNER JOIN Y ON M.ID = Y.ID
INNER JOIN X ON Y.ID=X.ID
```